# How to shrink Boostrap navbar into one line?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have a navbar with too many links so it goes onto another line. Is there any way to make it be limited onto one line every with all the content but just have it smaller?

My code:

```
<div class= "collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
     <ul class= "nav navbar-nav>
          <li class="active"><a href ="#" Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" Link </a></li>
```

But extended over 20 List indexes. The previous website was done using 22 columns in one row but I need to have the navigation to be responsive.

I also have an issue with the text going across one line rather than splitting which forces the navbar links to be even bigger, e.g;

```
<li> <a href="#" Health and Safety Policy</a></li>
```

This would just force the navbar onto another line immediately as it's too big.

I have tried making the text smaller, using line breaks and putting the navbar into a row class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to a vertical menu on small screen and horizontal menu on desktop.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Heart is where home is</li>
    <li>We live to work for our clients</li>
    <li>You might want to see our work</li>
    <li>Find us on google maps before visiting</li>
    <li>Got FAQs? search or contact us to get sorted</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and css

```
ul,li{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
li{
  list-style:none;
  border-bottom:none;
  text-decoration:underline;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
}
li:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  color:lightgrey;
}
nav
{
 display:block;
 color:white;
 background:grey;
 width:300px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:922px){
  nav{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
  }
  nav,
  ul{
    display:flex;
    background:lightblue;
  }
  li{
    transition: color 1s ease-in;
  }
  li:hover{
    color:grey;
  }
}
```

I have created a codepen. [Have a look](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/wYqagM) and if this solves your problem.